# Web.Config Configuration error while Publishing the site from Local to Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration, web-config

I currently published my site and done all the necessary things to host my project on the server.

The issue is that when I am running my project on the server, I am getting the below **Configuration error**

*Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I am getting these error at line no 52 of which the code is mentioned below.

```
 <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultCSRConnection" applicationName="/" />
```

Do let me know what necessary things I have to do to resolve this. Please suggest.!

Comment: I mean did System.Web.Providers actually end up on the server? Look in your /bin folder in your deployment dir and check that it actually got sent up.

Comment: @JTolley: Yes i looked the bin folder and there it was everything fine according to me..!!

Answer (score -2):

set Copy Local=true and ensure to use same version of .net framework.

Comment: In the Package Manager Console installe new packages Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core

Comment: yes  Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers 
AND 
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core

Comment: I am getting message as `CSRProject already has a reference to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Providers 2.0.0'.`, for bioth the package i am getting the message

Comment: ok look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.100).aspx) for change copy-local

Comment: I think, this will not resolve my present issue what I am facing. There is some dll file issue.!

Comment: OK will implement and let you know.!!